# Undefined reference to `fftw_init_threads' while installing pHash library

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, phash

I am trying to install pHash library on ubuntu, i installed libfftw3 and all the required libraries. Everything is Ok when I run ./configure command, but when i try to run the 'make' command this error always appear : undefined reference to `fftw_init_threads'.

make command :

```
g551683@sst-p1310007fl:~/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/src'
Making all in bindings
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/bindings'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/bindings'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/bindings'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/bindings'
Making all in examples
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/examples'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O2 -ffast-math -O3  -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o test_texthash test_texthash.o ../src/libpHash.la -lmpg123 -lsamplerate -lsndfile -lswscale -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec   -lpng -ljpeg -lfftw3
libtool: link: g++ -O2 -ffast-math -O3 -o .libs/test_texthash test_texthash.o  -L/usr/local/lib ../src/.libs/libpHash.so -lssl -lcrypto /usr/local/lib/libmpg123.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so -ldl /usr/local/lib/libsamplerate.so -lsndfile -lswscale -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so -lz /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a -lm
test_texthash.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
test_texthash.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b1): undefined reference to `fftw_init_threads'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:323: recipe for target 'test_texthash' failed
make[2]: *** [test_texthash] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6/examples'
Makefile:419: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/g551683/Documents/pHash-0.2.9.6'
Makefile:298: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone help me to solve this error!

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW.html):

> First, programs using the parallel complex transforms should be linked with `-lfftw3_threads -lfftw3 -lm` on Unix, or `-lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm` if you compiled with OpenMP. You will also need to link with whatever library is responsible for threads on your system (e.g. `-lpthread` on GNU/Linux) or include whatever compiler flag enables OpenMP (e.g. `-fopenmp` with gcc).

You are not linking against this `fftw3_threads` library, nor to the `pthread` library.